# for loop to limiting drawing on a map

Tags: android

I want to draw only 3 circles on a map so I used for loop but did not work why and what is the right way to use for loop on a map

here is my code with loop

```
    @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(point)   //set center
        .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
        .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
        .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
        .strokeWidth(5);

        for(int no=0 ; 0<3 ; no++){

         myCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 CircleOptions are exactly on the same point and the same size. So you only see the latest added CircleOption. You need differents point or size to see all the 3 CircleOption.

Comment: it dose not appear no one